# Uninstalling msi via msiexec fails with a 'only valid for applications installed' message

Tags: windows, windows-installer

We have a legacy software installation that we're trying to remove from our organisation. We have different versions and are trying to create a universal uninstaller for all versions. We've come across a particular release that doesn't seem to be able to be uninstalled via command line though. And it's proving difficult to create a workaround.

I've found the GUID of the application in the registry via

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

And the command I run is:

```
msiexec /x {080FDF44-6D15-4D2E-977E-74D5168198E7}
```

I get an application prompt asking me if I want to uninstall the product, so I click 'Yes'. And then it looks like it's starting but never actually does anything. So I dug round the registry and found another GUID in:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Userdata\S-1-5-18\Products\44FDF08051D6E2D479E7475D6118897E
```

If I run the same command as above with the different GUID, I get the application confirmation box asking for uninstall then after clicking OK, I get an error saying:

```
The installation package could not be opened. Verify the package exists and you can access it.......
```

I've been into C:\Windows\Installer into the folder with the above GUID and all that is in there is an icon and an *.mst file. In the root of C:\Windows\Installer, there is an *.msi called the same product in the details but with another version ID of:

```
8A2C4F93-4B31-4474-B9F2-2E51BF5D71A8
```

If I run the msiexec against that ID then I get a confirmation box again then another error which says

```
The action is only valid for products that are currently installed.
```

If I run the uninstaller, it uninstalls fine from the programs and features and uses the generated *.msi for the uninstalled (e.g. C:\Windows\Installer\241a6.msi and matches the product ID of 8A2C4F93-4B31-4474-B9F2-2E51BF5D71A8). This will change form machine to machine. Any other ideas on how to get this off in a neat and managed way?

Comment: Just for reference: [**Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1055933/129130).

Comment: Another reference: [**Why does MSI require the original .msi file to proceed with an uninstall?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208530/why-does-msi-require-the-original-msi-file-to-proceed-with-an-uninstall/1189524#1189524).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dredge the registry for ProductCode guids because they are obfuscated. If you don't really know the ProductCode, then look at ways of enumerating installed products. For example, the direct C++ way is MsiEnumerateProducts, and C# pinvoke equivalents, something like this:

[MSI Interop using MSIEnumRelatedProducts and MSIGetProductInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013425/msi-interop-using-msienumrelatedproducts-and-msigetproductinfo)

Then you will get the actual ProductCode and can get other info with it.

If sometimes it doesn't work when you are absolutely sure of the ProductCode, then it was perhaps installed in a per user context that's different from the one you're running the program with.

Also, for MSI-installed products Windows doesn't use the uninstall string, it just uses the ProductCode directly. Again, registry dredging is not the right thing when there are actual APIs specifically to enumerate installed MSI products.

If an uninstall requires access to the original MSI that it was installed from, then there are at least two reasons:

1. The MSI has an unconditional ResolveSource action that forces it to ask for the oroginal MSI file.
2. The cached version of the MSI file has been removed from C:\windows\installer.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply @PhilDW - I've since used Orca and got another productID which I now think is right. When I run the msiexec /x against it, it looks like it can't locate the original *.msi and asks for the path to it. The problem is that it doesn't actually exist anymore - I've tried using what I thought was the original *.msi but this has also failed. Any more ideas?

Comment: This is what happens when I install it from ARP:  http://i.imgur.com/89fF6I9.png but if I try and pass that in as follows, it fails: msiexec /x C:\Windows\Installer\241a6.msi

Comment: That image is the normal elevation dialog because you need admin rights to do the uninstall. Don't use the cached MSI in the command line!  Using the ProductCode guid is the correct answer, so stick with it.