# Converting a console app into a React app

Tags: reactjs, console-application

I'm looking into adding a version check into a react app. The best way i've found to check for the installed version on a computer is using MSIGetProductInfo. This thread illustrates how that can be done:
[MSI Interop using MSIEnumRelatedProducts and MSIGetProductInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013425/msi-interop-using-msienumrelatedproducts-and-msigetproductinfo?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I just don't really know where to start, or if this is even possible through a web interface.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, how can we help you with that? Do you have a specific question for us?

Comment: I'm new to react so i don't fully know its capabilities. I'm just trying to see if it is possible to do what the provided thread did within a react app. If so what would that look like?

Comment: A website cannot tell you information about the other programs installed on your computer.

Comment: So I thought that this was the case, but I was wondering if there was a work around. Is possible to create an api that would run such a program?