# How to find the installed version of a given software using the msi on a remote pc

Tags: c#

I've been doing some research into finding the version of installed software on a given computer. I am aware that this can be accomplished using powershell, but im looking at other options. This thread demonstrates how to find the installed version using the upgrade code on the local machine.
[MSI Interop using MSIEnumRelatedProducts and MSIGetProductInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013425/msi-interop-using-msienumrelatedproducts-and-msigetproductinfo?answertab=votes#tab-top).
Is it possible to use MSIenumRelatedProducts on a remote pc? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSI Interop using MSIEnumRelatedProducts and MSIGetProductInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013425/msi-interop-using-msienumrelatedproducts-and-msigetproductinfo)

Comment: Hahaha... it does help, but that is the thread that i provided... The goal of my post is to determine a way to accomplish this for a remote computer, not my local machine.