# Can MSIEnumRelatedProducts work against a remote computer

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use MSIEnumRelatedProducts against a computer other than your local computer?

This thread is similar to what I would like to accomplish, but it only works a the local computer. [MSI Interop using MSIEnumRelatedProducts and MSIGetProductInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013425/msi-interop-using-msienumrelatedproducts-and-msigetproductinfo?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Which is why i am asking if it can be ran against a remote pc.

Comment: we need more details and some code examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Added some sample code that does what i am looking to do, but i want to know if i can do it against a remote pc rather than local.

Comment: You just linked to another question,.... You need to post YOUR own code of what you have already tried.  Stackoverflow is not a code provider. We need to see what you have already tried and the error you are getting so we can help you.  That being said why are you trying to run this functionality on a machine where your installer is not running?

Comment: Did you read Stackoverflow guidelines for questions? You need a minimal reproduceable example.  Otherwise no one can help you.